# Autoplay Video in Chrome with Data-Saver enabled

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I would like to autoplay a small video on chrome with data saver enabled. When the data saver is enabled chrome is blocking all html5 autoplay and play initiation via. script.

```
<video autoplay muted controls>
     <source src="file.mp4">
</video>
```

Nevertheless there are some html5 players which still work. So it is possible and the question is how.

For example https://www.cb-1100.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=1144 (below the first post)

Comment: Isn't it because of `https` protocol ?

Comment: @Aria this was a thing in Chrome Versions 4n or 5n but not 6n